# what's the use of gitlab merge-request branches?

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-request

In gitlab, I came across one feature, where I can pull and checkout merge-request branch.

usually named like origin/merge-requests/123.

I was wondering what is the use, why would one want to checkout such branch? one can always checkout source branch of MR?

Comment: What if the request was merged and closed and the branch was deleted?

Comment: @matt Merged requests heads are removed after 14 days so merge-request branches are of no help in that case.

Comment: "*one can always checkout source branch of MR?*" The source branch could came from another repository so to check it out one has to investigate, find the other repo, add a remote, fetch. Too much trouble. Just fetch the origin and checkout the merge-branch head. Also the branches allow to merge from the command line.